# Is it logical to use EJBs in a desktop application for doing business logic?

Tags: java, ejb

Currently i'm developing a desktop application for smart homes, with this app you can read from/write to serial port(here's my business logic), store some information on a local database(which is installed on the same device).
another feature(and most importantly) of this app is to be able to set up something like airdroid, so that every device connecting to the same wifi could easily connect to the main device and control the house.(by showing them html pages)
Here's what i'm trying to do:
Set up an Application server like glassfish.
implement all the business logic(such as write/read to/from serial port, handling database jobs(with ORM) and...) into EJBs.
Use the EJB inside my desktop application.
Is it a logical or not?
Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a bit overkill to me. To use a full J2EE stack, you can pretty easy create a java server yourself that listens for commands on the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is logical. We are using EJBs with many desktop applications to implement business logic. If you feel yourself comfortable with EJBs, rather than with some other frameworks or standards, it is up to you to use it.

Of course, there are some pros and cons of doing so, but it is another topic, about which you can find multiple discussions on SO and Internet.